# Shift sidebar to bottom on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a page with two sidebars, one left and one right and I want to move the right sidebar to the bottom of the page on mobile but I can't get it to move.

I've been essentially throwing things at the wall and I don't really understand html/css that well so I apologize if this is a mess but here is what I have:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
}

header {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

header a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

label, select, button {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
        max-width: 1600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .search-form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center; 
    }

    #searchInput {
        width: calc(100% - 20px); 
        padding: 10px; 
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
    }

    .search-box input {
        width: 40%;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .search-box button {
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #222;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .convert {
        width: 100%;
        order: 2;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .convert_sidebar {
        float: right;
        width: 20%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: #333;
        order: 3; 
    }

    input[type="submit"] {
        width: calc(100% - 20px); 
        padding: 10px; 
    }

    .sidebar {
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: #333;
        padding: 0px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        order: -1; 
    }

    .sidebar h2 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .content {
        width: 70%; 
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 20px; 
        order: 0; 
    }

    .categories {
        padding: 5px;
    }
}


.title {
    text-align: center;
}

.title h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}


.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 20px;
}


.convert_sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 20%; 
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #333; 
}    


/* .clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
} */


.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header header {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


.content {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    flex-grow: 1; 
}

.content h1 {
    text-align: center;
}


.search-box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.search-box input {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}

.search-box button {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.categories {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.categories h2 {
    color: #fff;
}

.categories ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.categories li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.categories a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.categories a:hover {
    color: #3341ff;
}


.recipe {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.recipe h2 {
    color: #fff;
}

.recipe li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.recipe ol {
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ingredients ol {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<!-- recipe.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Holly's Kitchen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        {% include 'header.html' %}
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Navigation</h2>
          <form action="{{ url_for('search_results') }}" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." id="searchInput">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
          </form>
          <ul class="categories">
            {% for category in categories %}
              <li><a href="{{ url_for('category', category=category) }}">{{ category }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>


        <main class="recipe">

            <div class="recipe-details">
                <h2>{{ recipe.get('title', 'Recipe') }}</h2>
                <p>Serves: {{ recipe.get('serves', 'N/A') }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredients">
                <h3>Ingredients:</h3>
                <ol class="Ingredients">
                    {% for ingredient in recipe.get('ingredients', []) %}
                        {% if ingredient.get('section') %}
                            <li><strong>{{ ingredient.get('section') }}</strong></li>
                            <ol>
                                {% for item in ingredient.get('items', []) %}
                                    <li>{{ item.get('quantity', '') }} {{ item.get('item', '') | safe }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ol>
                        {% else %}
                            <li>{{ ingredient.get('quantity', '') }} {{ ingredient.get('item', '') | safe }}</li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ol>
            </div>

            <div class="instructions">
                <h3>Instructions:</h3>
                <ol class="Instructions">
                    {% for step in recipe.get('instructions', []) %}
                        <li>{{ step.get('step', '') }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ol>
            </div>

        </main>
        <div class="convert_sidebar">
          <h3>Unit Conversion</h3>
          <form id="conversion-form">
              <label for="from-amount">Value:</label>
              <input type="number" id="from-amount" name="amount" placeholder="Enter amount" required>

              <label for="from-unit">From Unit:</label>
              <select id="from-unit" name="from_unit">
                  <option value="cup (US)">Cup (US)</option>
                  <option value="cup (UK)">Cup (UK)</option>
                  <option value="oz">Ounce (oz)</option>
                  <option value="pint">Pint</option>
                  <option value="quart">Quart</option>
                  <option value="gallon">Gallon</option>
                  <option value="tsp">Teaspoon (tsp)</option>
                  <option value="tbsp">Tablespoon (tbsp)</option>
                  <option value="ml">Milliliter (ml)</option>
                  <option value="l">Liter (l)</option>
                  <option value="g (water)">Gram (water)</option>
                  <option value="g (granulated sugar)">Gram (granulated sugar)</option>
                  <option value="g (powdered sugar)">Gram (powdered sugar)</option>
                  <option value="g (brown sugar)">Gram (brown sugar)</option>
                  <option value="g (flour)">Gram (flour)</option>
                  <option value="g (butter)">Gram (butter)</option>
                  <option value="kg">Kilogram (kg)</option>
                  <option value="pinch">Pinch</option>
                  <option value="dash">Dash</option>
                  <!-- Add more units as needed -->
              </select>

              <label for="to-unit">To Unit:</label>
              <select id="to-unit" name="to_unit">
                  <option value="cup (US)">Cup (US)</option>
                  <option value="cup (UK)">Cup (UK)</option>
                  <option value="oz">Ounce (oz)</option>
                  <option value="pint">Pint</option>
                  <option value="quart">Quart</option>
                  <option value="gallon">Gallon</option>
                  <option value="tsp">Teaspoon (tsp)</option>
                  <option value="tbsp">Tablespoon (tbsp)</option>
                  <option value="ml">Milliliter (ml)</option>
                  <option value="l">Liter (l)</option>
                  <option value="g (water)">Gram (water)</option>
                  <option value="g (granulated sugar)">Gram (granulated sugar)</option>
                  <option value="g (powdered sugar)">Gram (powdered sugar)</option>
                  <option value="g (brown sugar)">Gram (brown sugar)</option>
                  <option value="g (flour)">Gram (flour)</option>
                  <option value="g (butter)">Gram (butter)</option>
                  <option value="kg">Kilogram (kg)</option>
                  <option value="pinch">Pinch</option>
                  <option value="dash">Dash</option>
                  <!-- Add more units as needed -->
              </select>

              <button type="button" onclick="convertUnits()">Convert</button>

              <div id="converted-result"></div>
          </form>
      </div>

      <script>
          function convertUnits() {
              const amount = document.getElementById('from-amount').value;
              const fromUnit = document.getElementById('from-unit').value;
              const toUnit = document.getElementById('to-unit').value;

              // Make an AJAX request to the server for unit conversion
              fetch('/convert_units', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  },
                  body: new URLSearchParams({ amount, from_unit: fromUnit, to_unit: toUnit }),
              })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                  if (data.error) {
                      console.error('Error:', data.error);
                  } else {
                      const convertedResult = `${amount} ${fromUnit} is: ${data.converted_amount} ${toUnit}`;
                      document.getElementById('converted-result').innerText = convertedResult;
                  }
              })
              .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
          }
      </script>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm guessing I have some conflicting settings somewhere but I can't find them.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can put three items in a line:

```css
#container > div {
    display: inline flow-root list-item;
}

#left {
    width: 19%;
    height:300px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#center {
    width: 60%;
    height:300px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#right {
    width: 19%;
    height:300px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

And if you want the third to appear below the other two items, increase its relative `width`. Since you want that to be done for mobile, do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #right {
    width: 79%;
  }
}
```

The above is called a media query, which checks for the criteria (max-width: 600px) and if true, then it applies the rules inside of it.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but when I try to implement that into my code I get them separated vertically instead of horizontally

Comment: @jesse_b can you edit your question and add the snippet of your trying to apply this? It would be great if I could check that. Maybe we can figure out the problem that way.

Comment: Unfortunately I eventually figured out a workaround and no longer have a broken version.  I did implement some of your ideas but ended up needing to finagle it a bit.  Here is my full css if interested: https://github.com/jessebutryn/recipes/blob/main/recipes/static/styles.css